# Remove Spacing between li

Tags: css

How can I remove spacing between the li found here?

http://blog.raveis.com/badge/b.html

Confused on how to do this and I don't want to use negative margins. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Make your `li` tags `display:block;` and `float:left;` (instead of `display:inline;`)

Comment: I think `float: left` will do. Tested on that Url with Firebug

Comment: As a side note, I think `display:inline` could work if you remove all the whitespace between the `li` tags.  But nobody wants to do that!  This is cleaner.

Comment: You can remove whitespace by replacing it by HTML comments (like<!-- -->this if SO doesn't eat the comment between like and this)

Comment: this works but using this way doesn't make the ul fit screen width:100%. how to keep both?

Answer (score 7):

Try this.

```
ul { font-size: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is rediculously late in the piece but I had the same problem today.

I fixed it by laying out my HTML like so, thereby removing any space between the list it:

```
<li>
  list-item 1
</li><li>
  list-item 2
</li><li>
  list-item 3
</li>
```

Example on [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/xael/pen/qyLYBZ)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want using list center, you can using:

```
 ul { text-align: center; }
 li { margin-right: -4px; }
```

How on this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kdddr8kL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Surprised that no one mentioned `line-height` on the `ul` element. It's possible I didn't get the full question because the original link is now broken, but generally, `line-height` might be the way to go