# Random quote in HTML using CodeIgniter

Tags: html, codeigniter, quotes

I am getting random quotes in my HTML (see image below), and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get rid of them. I have traced it right back to my model and there are now quotes there. I have also compressed all my code and there are still quotes.

[image]

Any one had this bug???

Here's my PHP code

```
<ul><?php foreach ($account_media as $value) : ?><li class="span2"></li>​<?php endforeach; ?></ul>
```

I am using CodeIgniter

[image]

UPDATE: ok this is from a while ago but thought i would update you all with my solution. DO NOT COPY AND PASTE FROM JSFIDDLE really hard to debug (paste code into text editor save as plain text and then delete the old code and replace with plain text version)

Comment: What are you echoing inside the <li>? And what are you using to compress your code?

Comment: clear your browser cache you might see a change

Comment: hi its was doing it before i compressed i just did it myself it will still output the "" with nothing inside the <li>

Comment: Seems like you look at your source code through the "Inspect element" of your browser. They tend to modify the actual code to dispay more information. Try looking at the source with right-click > Show code source.

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with CodeIgniter, it is the Inspect Element feature in Chrome which does not show the original source

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using `Inspect Element` instead of `View Source`? What does `View Source` show?

Quotes might appear as an indication for `empty` in element inspection. Or in your case, it might show that `<li>` tags are non-blocks and are separated.

And please, people, read/write it right, I'm so sick of seeing ignitOrs. It's CodeIgnit **E** r. And I don't point it out just because I'm some correct terminology freak, but because it makes your questions be parsed incorrectly by search engines.

The space between `<li>` elements is a css issue, refer to this article: [Remove Spacing between li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770601/remove-spacing-between-li)

Comment: Hi apologies for the spelling mistake!!! i did use view source and inspect element view source show no quotes at all and i know what your going to say whats your problem then we they all appear staggered in correctly? see updated question

Comment: That's a css problem, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770601/remove-spacing-between-li

Comment: i am using twitter bootstrap but ill check this out

Comment: If you're using twitter bootstrap, you'd better post all your code in a new question, it's definitely not related to CodeIgniter, tag it `css`, `twitter-bootstrap`, `html-lists`

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does this normally. It is nothing to be worried about.

View the source in the future for an absolute rendering of your HTML instead of inspecting the elements.

See screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]